# Karma test runner - fails to capture chrome

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, angularjs, socket.io, karma-runner

I'm using Yeoman to generate an AngularJS app. Running the `grunt serve` to preiview my app works fine, but when i try to run the tests using `grunt test` I get the following error on my console:

```
Running "karma:unit" (karma) task
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading karma-* from D:\dev\wamp\www\tests\app\node_modules
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin D:\dev\wamp\www\tests\app\node_modules/karma-chrome-launcher.
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin D:\dev\wamp\www\tests\app\node_modules/karma-coffee-preprocessor.
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin D:\dev\wamp\www\tests\app\node_modules/karma-firefox-launcher.
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin D:\dev\wamp\www\tests\app\node_modules/karma-html2js-preprocessor.
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin D:\dev\wamp\www\tests\app\node_modules/karma-jasmine.
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin D:\dev\wamp\www\tests\app\node_modules/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor.
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin D:\dev\wamp\www\tests\app\node_modules/karma-ng-scenario.
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin D:\dev\wamp\www\tests\app\node_modules/karma-phantomjs-launcher.
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin D:\dev\wamp\www\tests\app\node_modules/karma-requirejs.
DEBUG [plugin]: Loading plugin D:\dev\wamp\www\tests\app\node_modules/karma-script-launcher.
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.10.8 server started at http://localhost:8080/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser Chrome
DEBUG [launcher]: Creating temp dir at C:\Users\shlomis\AppData\Local\Temp\karma-91802655
DEBUG [launcher]: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe --user-data-dir=C:\Users\shlomis\AppData\Local\Temp\karma-91802655 --no-default-browser-check --no-first-run --disable-def
ault-apps --start-maximized http://localhost:8080/?id=91802655
WARN [watcher]: Pattern "D:/dev/wamp/www/tests/app/test/mock/**/*.js" does not match any file.
DEBUG [watcher]: Resolved files:
        D:/dev/wamp/www/tests/app/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/jasmine.js
        D:/dev/wamp/www/tests/app/node_modules/karma-jasmine/lib/adapter.js
        D:/dev/wamp/www/tests/app/app/bower_components/angular/angular.js
        D:/dev/wamp/www/tests/app/app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js
        D:/dev/wamp/www/tests/app/app/scripts/app.js
        D:/dev/wamp/www/tests/app/app/scripts/controllers/main.js
        D:/dev/wamp/www/tests/app/test/spec/controllers/main.js
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: D:\dev\wamp\www\tests\app\node_modules\karma\static/client.html
DEBUG [web-server]: serving: D:\dev\wamp\www\tests\app\node_modules\karma\static/karma.js
DEBUG [karma]: A browser has connected on socket 1ozU-x__3w49R5zevWXm
WARN [launcher]: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
Warning: Task "karma:unit" failed. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

- node v0.10.23
- Karma version: 0.10.8

What am I missing?

Comment: Does it work for another browser? I used to face a similar problem, but I remembered it working after I upgraded to the latest version of node.js. But seeing how you are already using the latest versions, there's something else amiss.

Comment: Solved it by changing the port to 9876 in the karma.conf.js file

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Changing the default port (8080) to **9876** in karma.conf.js file solved the issue for me

Comment: Doesn't solve the problem for me. My karma.conf.js doesn't specify a port, and 9876 should be the default already. Making it explicit doesn't help.

Comment: @mcv check if some other process is listening on ports 8080 / 9876

Comment: It turned out to be a weird configuration error on the machine itself. localhost didn't point to 127.0.0.1. Clearly anything that makes the browser not find the karma server results in this error.