# How to Unit Test an Ionic 2 Application Tutorial Karma Error: Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing

Tags: unit-testing, google-chrome, ionic2, karma-runner, isparta

I am currently learning how to unit test in Ionic 2 using Josh Monrony's [tutorial](http://www.joshmorony.com/how-to-unit-test-an-ionic-2-application/).

I am on Step 4: Create and Run a Unit Test.

When I run `npm test`, Chrome opens, but it never stops loading.

[image: blank chrome]

Then the console reports a timeout:

[image: console output]

What is causing the timeout?

Here is my karma.conf.js file:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({

    // base path that will be used to resolve all patterns (eg. files, exclude)
    basePath: '',


    // frameworks to use
    // available frameworks: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-adapter
    frameworks: ['jasmine', 'browserify'],


    // list of files / patterns to load in the browser
    files: [
      'node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js',        // TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new exports.Map()')
      'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js', // 'Uncaught reflect-metadata shim is required when using class decorators'
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js',        // Zone.js dependencies (Zone undefined)
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/jasmine-patch.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/async-test.js',
      'node_modules/zone.js/dist/fake-async-test.js',
      'app/**/*.spec.ts',
      {pattern: 'node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js.map', included: false, served: true}, // 404 on the same
      {pattern: 'www/build/**/*.html', included: false},
    ],

    // list of files to exclude
    exclude: [
      'node_modules/angular2/**/*_spec.js',
      'node_modules/ionic-angular/**/*spec*'
    ],


    // preprocess matching files before serving them to the browser
    // available preprocessors: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-preprocessor
    preprocessors: {
      '**/*.ts': ['browserify']
    },

    browserify: {
      debug: true,
      transform: [
        ['browserify-istanbul', {
          instrumenter: require('isparta'),
          ignore: ['**/*.spec.ts','**/*.d.ts'],
        }]
      ],
      plugin: [
        ['tsify']
      ]
    },


    // test results reporter to use
    // possible values: 'dots', 'progress'
    // available reporters: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-reporter
    reporters: ['progress'],


    // web server port
    port: 9876,


    // enable / disable colors in the output (reporters and logs)
    colors: true,

    proxies: {
      '/build': '/base/www/build'
    },

    // level of logging
    // possible values: config.LOG_DISABLE || config.LOG_ERROR || config.LOG_WARN || config.LOG_INFO || config.LOG_DEBUG
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,


    // enable / disable watching file and executing tests whenever any file changes
    autoWatch: true,


    // start these browsers
    // available browser launchers: https://npmjs.org/browse/keyword/karma-launcher
    browsers: ['Chrome'],


    // Continuous Integration mode
    // if true, Karma captures browsers, runs the tests and exits
    singleRun: false,

    // Concurrency level
    // how many browser should be started simultaneous
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

Here are similar questions, but they either don't have answers or the answers don't work:

- [Karma error - Chrome have not captured in 60000 ms, killing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23848153/karma-error-chrome-have-not-captured-in-60000-ms-killing)
- [Karma test runner - fails to capture chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20629578/karma-test-runner-fails-to-capture-chrome)
- https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1206

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and solved it deleting the npm directory and recreating it with npm update. That worked for me.